# Judging suitability for linguistics.SE or english.SE?

Tags: discussion, off-topic-questions, on-topic

Quite a few community members seem to agree that my most recent question belongs on ELU:

[What type of verb is "based"?](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/45446/what-type-of-verb-is-based)

However, my previous question had two upvotes, and the two questions before that also didn't receive any "should be migrated" comments even though the same users saw them:

[How can I tell if a word like "multiple" is being used as an adjective or determiner?](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/45438/how-can-i-tell-if-a-word-like-multiple-is-being-used-as-an-adjective-or-determ)
[How do "transform into" and "turn into" function syntactically?](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/45437/how-do-transform-into-and-turn-into-function-syntactically)
[Can "has been" be copular? Can the perfect tenses be copular?](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/45435/can-has-been-be-copular-can-the-perfect-tenses-be-copular)

I think all of these questions are about English quite specifically. I don't actually see the difference between all four (in terms of relevancy to linguistics, or relevancy to English language and usage).

How can I better judge in the future which site my question is more suitable for?

Comment: But all 3 questions cite English words. They're about English. and English is not like all other languages.